# create a private group via the yammer API

Tags: yammer

Is there a way to create a private group using the "yammer API"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use below code

```
yam.platform.request({
                    // yam.request({
                    url: "groups.json?name=Group_Name&private=true",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {},
                    success: function (group) {
                        console.dir(group);
                        getMyGroups();
                    },

                    error: function (group) {
                        console.error("There was an error with the request.");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: may I know the reason for down vote ? code is working for my project !

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can only join/leave an existing group for the current user.  See https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-groups

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new group in Yammer using REST API.

Endpoint:

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json

Parameters:
name - [string], group name
description - [string], group description
private - [true/false], indicates whether group is private
```

So you can send this request to Yammer API to create a new private group.

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?name=new_group_name&private=true
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you get the following response from Yammer:{
    "response": {
        "stat": "fail",
        "code": 17,
        "message": "Attempt to access a protected resource failed."
    }
}

Comment: I've just tested it in Fiddler and it works fine. The problem may be in auth token: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599921/yammer-rest-api-how-to-get-access-tokens-for-external-networks

Comment: This isn't a supported API at this time.

Comment: @BrianLyttle What's the status of this API ? Can we use it although it not documented/supported ? It seems to work eversince.

Comment: @BrianLyttle did anything change with regards to this not being "a supported API" over a year ago?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it looks like you can via an undocumented api.
See this code:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Scenarios/Provisioning.Yammer

See this specific line:

// Get Yammer Group - Creates if does not exist
    YammerGroup group = 
        YammerUtility.CreateYammerGroup(yammerGroupName, true, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YammerAccessToken"]);

Comment: Under the covers, the PnP code uses the exact same endpoint as Mahesh's answer.