# Yammer REST API: How to get access tokens for external networks?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, access-token, yammer

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application that reads data from Yammer. I've successfully acomplished authentication and getting messages from the "home" network.

Now I want to switch to another network and get messages from it. I've read all the [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/introduction/) and specifically the [Networks](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-networks) section which states the following:

> Facilitates switching a user between different Yammer networks. All
>   Yammer web requests contain a network permalink in the URL
>   (https://www.yammer.com/network_permalink/resource_path) to denote the
>   network context. API requests use a different OAuth token for each
>   user/network combination.
>
> Endpoint: Returns a list of networks to which the current user has
>   access. Supports included_suspended parameter.
>
> `GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/networks/current.json`

Ok, so I need to get the corresponding token for the user/network combination. Perfect.
I do a `GET` request to that `networks/current.json` endpoint and I get all the networks the current user has access to. Great. Now, where are the tokens? They aren't in the json response.

So...

- How do I get messages from external networks using the Yammer REST
  API via server-side code?
- How do I get the tokens for the external
  networks?

**UPDATE**

Following Brian's suggestion:

1. I do a `GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json` passing the current token in the authentication header (`Bearer: xxxxxxxxx`)
2. This returns the 2 networks the user I'm using is in. The home and the external. One thing I noticed is that the `user_id` is different for each network. I don't know if that's another user or if the same user has a different `user_id` for each network.
3. Now I want to get messages from the other network so I do a

`GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json`

but now using the token for the external network I got from the `tokens.json` endpoint.  But I get the following response:

```
{
  "response":
     {
      "stat":"fail",
      "code":17,
      "message":"Attempt to access a protected resource failed."
     }
 }
```

And again, according to the doc that endpoint is for impersonation and restricted to verified admin users in paid Yammer networks.

I have no clue really.

**UPDATE 2**

The process described in the above update works for the user (me) that created the Yammer App. I'm using. Other users can't get messages from external networks unless I'm in that network. So it seems like they are using my tokens, but that's impossible unless there's a bug in the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hit https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json. This topic is [covered](https://zapier.com/blog/api-quirks-yammer-external-networks/) over on the Zapier blog. Their blog specifies an access_token as a query string parameter, but that is no longer supported. Specify the access token for the current user on the Authorization header as shown on the Yammer developer site.

Comment: According to the [doc](http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-impersonation) that's the endpoint for impersonation. I already try that but I get tokens for other users. I mean, the JSON response contains a group of user_id/token combination but those user_id aren't the currently logged in one. So when I try to use one of those tokens to get messages from the corresponding external network, I don't get anything.

Comment: It's the tokens endpoint. You can post to it to get tokens for impersonation. I'll check later from another machine in my test network.

Comment: The problem was caused by the Yammer App not being deployed and so not having permission to access external networks.

Answer (score 2):

So far what i have discovered is this:
Due to some cross domain restriction, the SDK creates a hidden iframe on the page to serve as a proxy bridge to use the users primary network credentials and get access to external network resources. The **network parameter** is the key in the puzzle.

The obtained token can be then manually set for further requests whenever the page is reloaded, avoiding the login window to show up again.

```
yam.platform.login({ network: '{your-permalink-goes-here}' }, function (data) {

    console.log('login-status: ',data)
    if(data.status ==='connected')
        yam.platform.request({
            url: "oauth/tokens.json"     
            , method: "GET"
            , success: function (tokens) { console.log('user-tokens:',tokens); }
            , error: function (err) { alert("There was an error with the request."); }
        });
})
```

Then for next requests, setAuthToken does the trick.

```
yam.platform.setAuthToken('{the-token-goes-here}'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to work in SSO enabled Network, you need to globalize your app. For this you need to raise a ticket to the yammer  helpdesk.

Refer: [yammer oauth2 returning 403 Client Error: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127455/yammer-oauth2-returning-403-client-error-forbidden/30522798#30522798)