# Yammer API: How to get messages and access tokens for external networks?

Tags: windows, yammer

Hi i'm working on yammer API, in  (https://www.yammer.com/network_permalink/resource_path) for "resource_path" what we need to pass.

Comment: you can follow the example mentioned on this thread [Yammer REST API: How to get access tokens for external networks?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599921/yammer-rest-api-how-to-get-access-tokens-for-external-networks/25819879#25819879

Answer (score 0):

'resource_path' referrers to any API reference call such as;

https://www.yammer.com/network_permalink/api/v1/messages/following.json

and

https://www.yammer.com/network_permalink/api/v1/pending_attachments.json