# Yammer: can no longer access messages from other network using Yammer API

Tags: oauth-2.0, social-networking, yammer

I am part of two Yammer networks N1 and N2. N1 is my home network.

Since a few days/weeks, I can no longer access messages from the N2 network using the Yammer API.

Here's how I get messages from N1 (which is successful):

- get auth code by browsing to `https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[clientid]&redirect_uri=[redirecturi]`

  - results in [authcode_N1] (after loggin in; in URL)
- perform GET `https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=[clientid]w&client_secret=[secret]&code=[authcode_N1]`

  - results in JSON with [access_token1] (note: there is only one token in response)
- get messages by performing GET `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json`, with HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer [access_token1]`

  - result: messages from N1 only

Here's how I try to get messages from N2 (which fails):

- get auth code by browsing to `https://www.yammer.com/N2/dialog/oauth?client_id=[clientid]&redirect_uri=[redirecturi]`.

  - note 'N2' in URL
  - results in [authcode_N2] (wich is different then the one previously obtained for N1)
- perform GET `https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=[clientid]w&client_secret=[secret]&code=[authcode_N2]`

  - results in status 403, body `'Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application'`

Here's another attempt to get messages from N2 (which fails too):

- get tokens by performing GET on `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json`, with HTTP header 'Authorization: Bearer [access_token1]

  - results in JSON with two elements, both with a different network ID (one for N1 and one for N2) and a token for each network
  - note that the token for N1 in this JSON matches [access_token1] above
  - let's call the token for N2 in this JSON [access_token2]
- perform GET `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json`, with HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer [access_token2]`

  - response: `{"response":{"stat":"fail","code":17,"message":"Attempt to access a protected resource failed."}}`

Note that [clientid], [secret] and [redirecturi] are from our application. On its settings page (titled 'Registered applications') there is a green checkmark in the 'enabled' column and none in the 'global' column. In the 'Basic Info' section for this application, there is a green 'Deploy' button.
Maybe this is causing the problem (I have found some user responses in this direction about similar problems (see [Yammer REST API: How to get access tokens for external networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599921/yammer-rest-api-how-to-get-access-tokens-for-external-networks)))? But this would not explain why getting the messages from N2 used to work previously...

Please let me know how I could get the data from N2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json?access_token= with your N1 token to generate a token for all of your networks.
Read the N2 token from the response and call the yammer API with this token.

You can see how it works on the "famous" zapier "Api Quirks"
https://zapier.com/blog/api-quirks-yammer-external-networks/